# I cannot get a regex to match all letters, numbers, and the characters . ' " : - and / to work correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been scratching my head for a couple hours trying to come up with a regex that will find all strings that follow the pattern: lowercase or uppercase letters, numbers, and the characters `.` `:` `'` `"` `/` and `-`.

My current regex is:

```
var patt = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9:.\"/'-]+");.
```

For context here is how it is being used in form validation in JavaScript:

```
var quote = document.forms["myForm"]["quote"].value;
var quoteWordCount = quote.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
var patt = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9:.\"/'-]+");
var quoteResult = patt.test(quote);
if (quote.length < 2) {
    alert("quote can't be less than 2 characters");
    return false;
}
if (quoteWordCount < 4) {
    alert("Your quote must contain 4 or more words.");
    return false;
}

if (quoteResult) {
    alert("Please enter a valid quote.");
    return false;
}
```

Right now, it is for some reason rejecting every single string I give it, both the ones it should reject and the ones it should not. For example it will reject:

> "Hello there fellow programmers"

and will also reject:

> "Hello<<>> there!! fellow programmers."

Comment: Maybe removing the "not these symbols" part, the negation, helps, and escaping certain characters for safety reasons may be preferrable, e.g. `-` inside `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your regex:

- Don't use the negation `^`.
- Add space to your regex because it is an allowed character between words.
- Match the entire line by starting your regex with `^` and ending it with `$`.

The resulting regex is `^[a-zA-Z0-9 :.\"/'-]+$`. Here is a test:

```js
var patt = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 :.\"/'-]+$");

var quote = "Hello there fellow /programmers";
console.log(patt.test(quote));
quote = "Hello<<>> there!! fellow programmers.";
console.log(patt.test(quote));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
[A-Za-z0-9:."'-]+
```

might work OK.

```js
const regex = /[A-Za-z0-9:."'-]+/g;
const str = `abcad^&*
ABCadfa909%^&*
abc-9.8ad-"ABC"-adf'-'`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1PW6qY/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/1PW6qY/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]